# Getting this "large mesh" that cannot be removed after a boolen union. What is it?

Tags: boolean-modifier

I'm using Blender 3.6 and did boolean union on a few objects. I got the result I wanted, but there are some areas that are "shadowed". When I hide the shadowed meshes (like the ones pointed by yellow arrows), it reveals a big mesh underneath and somehow, I can't select/edit that mesh. What is it? Is there a way to clean it?
[image]